# Как добраться до элементов коллекции без циклов?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Всем привет! Я новичок. Есть такой вопрос, получаю я [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Readonlycollection` мне нужно добраться до `URL` картинки путь получается длинный 
`Attachments.Instance.Photo1280`. Мне для этого нужно три раза запускать цикл foreach? Есть ли методы по проще?  Спасибо!

Comment: Вы получаете `ReadonlyCollection<T>` для какого-то типа `T`?

Comment: Извините. Я не совсем Вас понял. Конструкция такая  var wall = api.Wall.Get(-group.Id.Value, out totalCount, count);

Comment: `var` — это хорошо. А какого типа `wall` на самом деле, вы знаете?

Comment: public ReadOnlyCollection<Post> Get(
    long ownerId, 
    out int totalCount, 
    int? count = null, 
    int? offset = null, 
    WallFilter filter
) Судя по всему Post

Comment: Хорошо. А какие свойства есть в `Post`?

Comment: Нужно парсить JSON или что? Где мне посмотреть на эти свойства?

Comment: Ну, у вас должна быть документация к API. Или нажмите F12 на этом типе в Visual Studio.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23845/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-vladd).

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то данную задачу более компактно можно решить при помощи LINQ. Опишите более подробно структуру объектов и какую коллекцию хотите получить на выходе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не пробовали с LINQ?

Не уверен как это будет для вашего примера, и что вам в итоге нужно, но это сильно упростит ваши циклы:

```
posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attachments! = null).FirstOrDefault(a => an instance...
```

И так далее(быть может условия Where? Select?)

Прочитайте о такой возможности подробнее, по вопросу не совсем понятно. И скриншот расходится во мнении с Вами, там показан другой путь.

```
//более удобный вид цикла
arrObj.ForEach(ary, delegate(int elem) { sum += elem; });

//это можно заменить 
//var cnt = 0; 
//foreach(var user in users) 
//    cnt++; 

//так называемым "аккумулятором"
var cnt = users.Aggregate((e, acc) => acc + 1);
```

Больше информации к примеру [в этом блоге](http://force-net.com/2012/06/blog-post.html)